# Joining a pre determined voice channel via channel ID when a command is run using discord.js-commando

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to have a command that will join a voice channel in Discord, from a channel id, when the command is run.

I am using Commando, as well, so the command so far looks like this:

```
async run(message, args) {
        var channel = client.channels.cache.get("ChannelID");
        channel.join();
}
```

However, when I tried this method, I get the following error when running the command:
`ReferenceError: client is not defined`

I tried delcaring a discord client using `const client = new Discord.Client();` at the start, and this made the problem worse.

Is there a different syntax or method I could use in order to get the channel ID and then join the channel?

Answer (score 1):

The fix is quite easy.

You have two options, either create the client in a separate file from your index and export it or pass it on as a parameter when you execute your command.

The last one is the easier option so I'll focus on that.

Your command handler should in some way contain this.

```
// command is just a placeholder here
command.execute(message, args);
```

Now you can just pass the client as another parameter.

```
command.execute(message, args, client);
```

In your command file you now need to include it when you execute the file.

```
async run(message, args, client) { // the order must be the same as above
    // your code here
}
```

If you don't want or can't do the above, you can also get the channel ID via the message object.

```
var channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("ChannelID");
```

EDIT:

Alternativly you could create your client in a separate file and import it into all the locations you need. Lets create a file called `client.js` and put it in the same directory as your `index.js`.

```
-- Your bots folder
    - client.js
    - index.js
    - // all your other files
```

Now we create the client in `client.js` and export it.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = client;
```

Next step is to delete the corresponding lines in your `index.js` so you don't create a client twice and import the new instance of your client.

```
const client = require('./client.js');
```

This you can do in every file you need your client in. All you need to change is the relative path to `client.js`.

Comment: @Wortthy Alpaca Thank you! So much!

Just out of curiosity, what is command a placeholder for here? Commando acts as the command handler in this case, so while I know I could pass client as an argument in the async function, im not entirely sure if that is all I would need to do.

Comment: Well, you need to pass it to the inital line of code that executes the command. I never used commando, but you can probably pass additional arguments to it. If that doesn't work I edited the answer and included a way to export your client.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, just add `this`.
For example `this.client.channels.cache.get("ChannelID");`